# How do I validate text boxes with in a a group box using control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So I know how to do just the textboxes. But the validation code will skip within a groupbox, because the control is not within the form. I was trying to somehow call the specific groupbox form but I don't know the exact syntax. Sorry I am new at this, if I don't have enough info please let me know. Also if you have references to control or groupbox commands it would be helpful. thanks!

```
For Each cntrl As Control In Controls
            If TypeOf cntrl Is TextBox Then
                cntrl.BackColor = Color.White
                If cntrl.Text = String.Empty Then
                    cntrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    cntrl.Focus()
                    Return False
                End If

For Each cntrl As GroupBox In Controls
            If TypeOf cntrl Is TextBox Then
                cntrl.BackColor = Color.White
                If cntrl.Text = String.Empty Then
                    cntrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    cntrl.Focus()
                    Return False
                End If
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQbo0.png)

Comment: Every control has a `Controls` collection. That of the form only contains those controls directly on the form. If you want to access the controls on a `Panel`, you have to use the `Controls` collection of that `Panel`.

Comment: That said, you are handling validation incorrectly. If you want to validate a control then you should handle that control's `Validating` event. You set `e.Cancel` to indicate whether it failed validation or not. By default, a control will be validated when the user tries to leave it and it will refuse to lose focus if it fails. If you don't want to validate as you go, set `CausesValidation` to `False` on each control and then call `ValidateChildren` on the form when you want to validate.

Comment: If you want to access controls of a specific type, use something like `For Each tb In Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()`. Then you'll get nothing but `TextBoxes`.

Comment: Note that, if you want to validate multiple controls in the same way, as always, you can use a single method to handle multiple events by adding them all to the `Handles` clause. Inside the method, you use the `sender` parameter to access the object that raised the event.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments, proper WinForms validation should look like this:

```vb
Private Sub TextBoxes_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.Validating,
                                                                                 TextBox2.Validating,
                                                                                 TextBox1.Validating
    Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

    If tb.TextLength = 0 Then
        tb.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        e.Cancel = True
    Else
        tb.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ValidateChildren() Then
        'All controls contain valid data so go ahead and use it.
    End If
End Sub
```

You will now validate all the controls whose `Validating` event you handle, wherever they are located, and none that you don't. If you set `CausesValidation` to `False` on all the controls then no validation will occur until you call `ValidateChildren`. Even if you do want to validate as you go, you should still call `ValidateChildren` because that will ensure that even those controls that have never received focus will be validated.